# Does this basic class properly exemplify how to make a class in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand initialization and class and OOP in Python 3, and I am curious if this is properly showing how to do so? Your kindness is appreciated.

CODE:

```
 class bank:
    def __init__(self, name, balance):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = balance
    def withdrawal(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount
    def add(self, amount):
        self.balance += amount
    def req_balance(self, balance):
        print(self.balance)

bob = bank("bob",5000)
bob.add(5500)
bob.req_balance(bob.balance)
```

Comment: This is better asked in [codereview.se] I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your example class has an initializer, instance variables, and instance methods. Each method has an explicit `self` as the first argument. One stylistic nitpick is that classes in Python should start with a capital letter so calling this class `Bank` would be better in my opinion. Are there any specific questions about this class that you have?

Comment: Also, the `balance` argument is superfluous in the `req_balance` function.

Comment: @VaibhavSagar Would this be a correct representation of inheritance as well? I am just making sure I am grasping everything correctly.

Comment: class store(Bank):
    items = {}
    def buy(self, item, price):
        self.items[item]=price
        self.balance -= price
        self.req_balance()
bob = store('bob',4555)
bob.add(400)
bob.req_balance()
bob.buy('dog',56)

Comment: @Vaibhav        ________________

Comment: Yes, but there is a problem with your code in that `items` is shared amongst all instances of `store`. You might want to declare a separate `__init__` for `store` that calls the superclass using `super().__init__`.

Comment: This is definitely better suited to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).